# js prompt validation to one of three words

Tags: javascript, validation, command-prompt

i'm trying to learn js. so, for learing i want to write a little game called rock, papper, scissors.
Now i want to do a prompt(), where the user have to type in what he want to choose. but if he wrote none of the 3 possible answers (rock, paper, scissors) he have to do it again.

my code so far:

```
function validateUserChoice() {
var localUserChoi = prompt("Please choose rock, paper or scissors");

while (localUserChoi != "rock" || localUserChoi != "paper" || localUserChoi != "stone") {
    alert("You have to type one of the words: rock, paper, scissors");
    localUserChoi = prompt("Bitte geben Sie rock, paper oder scissors ein");
}

userChoice = localUserChoice;
}
```

i know the condition of the while-loop is wrong, but what do i have to write in it?

cheers
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
var answer = '';
var options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
while (!~options.indexOf(answer)) {
  answer = prompt('Please choose: "'+ options.join(', ') +'"');
};
```

**Explanation:**
`answer` is not matching any of the array values by default, so `prompt` is done inside while loop. After it matches with the index of array (0, 1, or 2), the index is converted with:

- ~ = which causes addition of 1 to the index and then negation [this makes 0 as -1 which evaluates as `true`
- ! = which converts it to opposite boolean (where true becomes false to quit while loop).

Comment: yes, it works! thanks a lot for you help and your explanation.